# show HTML formatted error message with HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that serves up media files.  If a file is not found, I show a simple message on the page to the user with the code below:

```
        var fileNotFoundResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        if (!File.Exists(mediaFile.FilesystemLocation))
        {
            fileNotFoundResponse.Content = new StringContent("File not found! <br /> Please contact <a href='mailto:support@sbcdef.com'>support@sbcdef.com</a>");
            return ResponseMessage(fileNotFoundResponse);
        }
```

The problem is, is that it's just plain text on a white page that doesn't show HTML and I want it to be able to display the HTML.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't sending the client the correct ContentType header, and likely need to set the [**HttpResponse.ContentType**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) string:

```
fileNotFoundResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
fileNotFoundResponse.Clear();
fileNotFoundResponse.BufferOutput = true;
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**: If you need UTF8 support, try this:

```
fileNotFoundResponse.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
```